# Allegro can't be linked correctly

Tags: c++, allegro

Today I installed allegro 5.as the [a link](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Install_Allegro5_From_SVN/Linux/Debian).
But When I start to write a very simple code.
When I compiled using `"g++ allegro_test.cpp -o output.out pkg-config --libs allegro5.0"`
it returns that `allegro undefined reference to al install system`.
When I use `pkg-config --cflags --libs allegro-5.0`.
It only returns `-lallegro`.
What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a typo? It only returns `-lallergo` ?

Try to compile with: `g++ allegro_test.cpp -o output.out -lallegro`

Comment: yes it only returns -lallergo.I suppose there may be something wrong when it is set up.

Comment: You mean it returns alleRGo not alleGRo?

Comment: sorry it's my mistake.

Comment: I try to compiler with "g++ allegro_test.cpp -o output.out -lallegro".but still can't compile it.